# Adding view on tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, view, uiview, tableview

I have tall tableView and I want to add view on it, I want that it too will be tall.
I add view with this code but it only in one view height - 568 points.

```
_backgroundSelectionView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
_backgroundSelectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.95 alpha:1];
[self.tableView addSubview:_backgroundSelectionView];
```

How can I add view on all screen?

Comment: Why you want to add a view on top of table view?
Do you want to add header or footer to it.
To achieve want you are saying -add tableView and backgroundSelectionView to another view.
`[mainView addsubView:self.tableView]`
`[mainView addsubView:_backgroundSelectionView]`

Comment: I need to color all screen in some color when I select tableView cell with popping cell

Comment: If I am not wrong self here is UITableViewController ?

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewController provides UITableView and you cannot add subviews to tableViewController on top of tableview easliy.
**Instead of using UITableViewController change it to UIViewController**(which will conforms to UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate), with this you can add views(tableView and any other subView) on main UIView of UIViewController.